# Magento cron job only sends newsletter when explicitly run

Tags: magento, cron

I have set up my cronjob for Magento to run every two hours, that is the quickest my host can set it to. However, newsletters don't get sent until I actually go into my host's control panel and click the 'Run' button for the particular cronjob.

What did I do wrong? My cron path is set as: `/bin/sh /usr/www/users/FTP_USER/cron.sh`

Comment: this is the question for your hosting provider

Comment: Don't you think I already asked them? All they told me was that the cron was executed and that it was on Magento's side where stuff didn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the event observers are loaded based on the context (adminhtml,frontend or in your case crontab). The newsletter sending observer is not on the crontab list so it cannot send emails.

See this article: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/01/magento-events-explained-and-a-few-gotchas-avoided/

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is highly likely to be a permissions/PATH problem of one form or other. When you manually trigger the event by clicking something in the control panel, it is probably getting ran as the Apache user (www-data or equivalent, depending on the platform). The cron will most likely be running as a different user to this.

Assuming you're referring to the core newletters cron `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Observer::scheduledSend`, it's unlikely there's any problem with `cwd` being incorrect for relative include paths. This leaves the most likely culprits a.) the cron user doesn't have execute permissions on your cron.sh, b.) the cron user doesn't have access to the mail application on the server, because it isn't include in the users PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the cron.sh script hasn't been up to it. Consequently I just run the cron.php . This requires php cli being setup properly with enough RAM and sensible timeouts.

In your crontab try:

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/USER/public_html/cron.php >> /home/USER/public_html/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

I also keep a log file in var/log/cron.php so that I can see errors made during a cron job.